# Some difficulties writing a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
IsServiceable = _context.Review.Any(r => r.SiteId == x.Id) ? _context.Review.All(r => r.SiteId == x.Id && r.IsValid == true) : true
```

But as you can see it is not effective because I try to access the database twice in the same row.

I need to write single query(LINQ TO ENTITY) to check if the table named `Reviews` 
has at least one row 
where `siteId=5` if it doesn't it has to return **true**,
If table Reviews has at least one row I need to check a boolean column named `isValid` if, there is at least one row where `siteId=5` and `isValid` column is `false`  I need to return `false`.

Comment: at least make the sample code names and description fit...

Comment: You have example row above!
And the explanation bellow.

Comment: yeah, sure, and the LINE has InspectionReview table not Review, and row  has IsNormal property not isValid

Comment: People should stop writing what they are doing in code and just try to explain what they are trying to do... So what you want is to check if there exists a valid review for a site or not?

Comment: god, what a mess, you start with some artificial problem which now appears to be something else, you say "if, there is at least one row where siteId=5 and isValid column is false I need to return false.", this does not translate to there is any with isValid = true

Comment: To adequately answer, we need to know the return value for all cases. You state that: if no rows found with siteId=5, return true. If at least one row found with siteId=5 and isValid=false, return false. What if all rows with siteId=5 had isValid=true? What should be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your solution lies in the fact that only in one case do you need to return **false** - everything else returns **true**. Therefore, if you find one row where sideId=5 and isValid = false, then return false. Otherwise, return true. Based on your code, I suggest something like the following:

```
IsServiceable = _context.InspectionReview.Any(r => r.SiteId == x.Id && r.isValid == false) ? false : true;
```

Comment: why not IsServiceable = !_context.InspectionReview.Any(r => r.SiteId == x.Id && r.isValid == false) :)

Comment: No!!there is two cases where I need to return FALSE!

Comment: not according to what you have said so far, be preceise or accept the answer above, its perfectly correct for what YOU HAVE ASKED FOR

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have navigation properties so you could try

```
IsServiceable = _context.Site.Any(s => s.Id == x.Id && s.Reviews.Any(r => r.IsValid));
```